# 18.04 updates break the grub and prevent booting

Tags: 18.04, grub2, updates

Today I encountered an issue which prevented my system from booting. The system is a fresh install, as I recently reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04.3 via a live USB with the official Ubuntu ISO.

This is my third or fourth attempt, and I am experiencing the same issue:

- Install the system with default parameters
- Reboot immediately after installation, no issue.
- Update my system. Right now it's broken, so I don't have it anymore, but I just ran the regular updates right after installing the system.
- After rebooting again, my system appears broken. I can no longer boot to Ubuntu. The system continues to show the grub menu and then fails if I select any option.
- Every time this happens, I reinstall Ubuntu 18.04.3 and have the same issue (update and get stuck in a boot loop).
- We have an error showed by dmesg:

> ```
> EDAC amd64: Error: F0 not found, device 0x1460 (broken BIOS?)
> EDAC amd64: Error: Errorprobing instamce: 0
> ```

We reproduced this error with another computer (edit: 3 other computers) with a week-old install and ran into the exact same problem. The other computers have similar very recent hardware (most recent AMD CPU, AMD Epyc 7302p).

A colleague made the update and had the issue as well. He had to revert his kernel version from 5.0.0-36-generic to 5.0.0-35-generic to recover a functional system.

**Update:** Apparently, the error comes from a package upgrade. Because I installed Ubuntu 18.04 from scratch, from a live USB with the kernel version 5.0.0-23-generic and when letting the installer downloading the updates during the installation, it upgrades the kernel to version 5.0.0-36-generic without breaking the grub. However, when I tried to upgrade the other packages (with apt upgrade) broke the grub once again.

During the upgrade, I saw that one package was modifying some files in the /boot partition but, unfortunately, I didn't have the time to see which one.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: 18.04.10? would you say 18.10 instead?

Comment: Right now it's broken so I don't have it anymore, but I just ran the regular updates right after installing the system so I assume that it would not upgrade ubuntu itself to a non-LTS version like that. Maybe I'm wrong idk

Comment: Also, you said that you installed update after fresh install, you can enable that option inside Ubuntu installer

Comment: Isn't it because you try to install a *random* package?

Comment: I only installed the updates without touching anything else, jist to try if the update was the cause. And after that update it broke the grub again. I am reinstalling right now but with the minimal version to test.

Comment: did you try to restart the computer without doing any updates, to see if GRUB is basically installed well?

Comment: Yes, if I don't update I can reboot without issue. I don't even see the grub actually, I can directly log in.

Comment: There is no such thing as Ubuntu 18.04.10. (And assume that by Ubuntu 18.04.03 you mean 18.04.3?)

Comment: Yep, sorry, I mixed up with some package version or something. I corrected it.

Comment: I'm also running into this issue with bare metal systems installed with Foreman 1.24. In my case, this happens on the first boot after installation. There's no chance for me to update any packages or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue after a series of trusted updates on two Dell Precision 5820s.
The first has two OSs on separate 2 TB drives:

- sda=Ubuntu18.04
- sdb=Windows10

The second has three OSs on separate 2 TB drives:

- sda=Ubuntu18.04
- sdb=Fedora31
- sdc=Debian9

On the first I ran the following :

1. `sudo apt update`
2. I invoked Software Updater.
3. I allowed it to update all.
4. when it came to updating GRUB, it asked whether I wanted to replace mine, stay with the local, or compare the two. I chose to compare the local and the new, which sounded simplea console readout stating *Setting up shim-signed (1.37~18.04.3+15+1533136590.3beb971-0ubuntu1) ...* when doing some update (even though I said NO to doing that!) and required a restart to free up the system.
5. When back in, I opened a terminal and ran `sudo update-grub`
6. I restarted again and got in.

The second system (in sync since both running from yesterday's Dell Restore flash install that overcame the "login loop" caused by AMD not getting their drivers in before Dell froze the system release with the 2100X graphics card endlessly awaiting login input which could not be read in 16.04 code/kernel) was different because I said (at the same query about a GRUB update) that I wanted to stay with the local one which allowed me to select/run my three OSs.
After a restart it gave me errors on all three, which tells me GRUB is broken (as is the Software Installer code)

- Ubuntu: I used <kbd>F12</kbd> to bypass the GRUB menu, and selected Ubuntu but it failed.

  ```
  0.3294701 Kernel offset: ...
  0.3294911 --- [ end Kernel panic - not synching: VFS: 
  Unable to mount fs on unknown-block(0,0)
  ```

  So I rebooted.
- Debian: I used <kbd>F12</kbd> to bypass the GRUB menu, and selected Debian, but it failed.
  It went to the System Tester window which I hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to leave, and then rebooted.
- Fedora: I used <kbd>F12</kbd> to bypass the GRUB menu, and selected Fedora. At first, it seemed fine.
  I got in and it auto-updated.
  Then, it went into the EFI menu, where I again selected Fedora.
  It got to the purple Ubuntu *lo-res* screen and hung up there.

This is tiring. There is supposed to be *not-the-coder* QA'ing of the release process and full regression (and build, and acceptance, and release) testing, esp. on all areas affected by modified code, adding new tests for new code! This is starting to look like the model of Microsoft and Apple releases, where once it is working, I dare not ever click *[Ok]* to update queries for a well-founded fear of getting an untraceable and fatal (no work-around) high priority/high severity "issue" wasting more of my time, wherein I have to do the QA and testing someone else skipped.

That is not how releasing is defined by ACM, IEEE, ISO, SQA, et. al. I have to replace an unsaved file on a system that cannot be logged into, i.e., reinstall after zeroing out.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this, with AMD EPYC 7452 32-Core Processors:

```
Aug 28 13:57:40 server01 kernel: [    8.196170] MCE: In-kernel MCE decoding enabled.
Aug 28 13:57:40 server01 kernel: [    8.201319] EDAC amd64: Node 0: DRAM ECC enabled.
Aug 28 13:57:40 server01 kernel: [    8.201320] EDAC amd64: F17h detected (node 0).
Aug 28 13:57:40 server01 kernel: [    8.201375] EDAC amd64: Error: F0 not found, device 0x1460 (broken BIOS?)
Aug 28 13:57:40 server01 kernel: [    8.201378] EDAC amd64: Error: Error probing instance: 0
Aug 28 13:57:40 server01 kernel: [    8.320565] EDAC amd64: Node 0: DRAM ECC enabled.
```

The fix was to install the LTS Enablement Stacks (also called HWE or Hardware Enablement) kernels:

```
apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04
```

Now, the system boots with this, and doesn't throw an error:

```
Aug 28 14:07:39 server01 kernel: [  117.977960] MCE: In-kernel MCE decoding enabled.
Aug 28 14:07:39 server01 kernel: [  117.985049] EDAC amd64: Node 0: DRAM ECC enabled.
Aug 28 14:07:39 server01 kernel: [  117.985051] EDAC amd64: F17h_M30h detected (node 0).
Aug 28 14:07:39 server01 kernel: [  117.985283] EDAC MC: UMC0 chip selects:
Aug 28 14:07:39 server01 kernel: [  117.985285] EDAC amd64: MC: 0: 65536MB 1: 65536MB
Aug 28 14:07:39 server01 kernel: [  117.985286] EDAC amd64: MC: 2: 65536MB 3: 65536MB
```

- Ubuntu fixed a similar bug in Ubuntu 19.10, but doesn't exist in the main 18.04 kernel yet: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1869235
- OpenSUSE has a similar bug with a fix at https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000019537